# How can I apply translate() to an attribute value in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, msxml

I have a function that returns XML data and want to write a test for it to check if it returns the expected result. The XML data looks like this:

```
<Session Id="OF1qxev4OSZcIbsS">
  <User Id="10001">
    <LoginName>SelfTest</LoginName>
    <RealName>SelfTest User</RealName>
  </User>
  <StartTime>2015-11-13T13:01:59Z</StartTime>
  <EndTime>2015-11-13T15:01:59Z</EndTime>
</Session>
```

The XML contains data that is different upon each request so before comparing against the expected result I use XSLT to replace the variable data (session ID attribute and content of StartTime/EndTime nodes) with some fixed pattern. The XSL file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:variable name="uid-chars">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="uid-mask" >IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="timestamp-nums">0123456789</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="timestamp-mask">DDDDDDDDDD</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- copy attributes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <!-- copy child elements -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <!-- trim whitespace -->
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- normalize uids -->
  <xsl:template match="@Id">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $uid-chars, $uid-mask)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="StartTime|EndTime">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="timestamp"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- normalize timestamps -->
  <xsl:template mode="timestamp" match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $timestamp-nums, $timestamp-mask)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the expected output would look like this:

```
<Session Id="IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII">
  <User Id="10001">
    <LoginName>SelfTest</LoginName>
    <RealName>SelfTest User</RealName>
  </User>
  <StartTime>DDDD-DD-DDTDD:DD:DDZ</StartTime>
  <EndTime>DDDD-DD-DDTDD:DD:DDZ</EndTime>
</Session>
```

Unfortunately with the current XSL above the normalization only works for StartTime/EndTime values but not for the session ID:

```
<Session Id="OF1qxev4OSZcIbsS">
  <User Id="10001">
    <LoginName>SelfTest</LoginName>
    <RealName>SelfTest User</RealName>
  </User>
  <StartTime>DDDD-DD-DDTDD:DD:DDZ</StartTime>
  <EndTime>DDDD-DD-DDTDD:DD:DDZ</EndTime>
</Session>
```

What is the correct way to apply the translate() function to attribute values?

Note: I used the XSLT engine from MSXML6 in my tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `xsl:copy` in your template that matches the `Id` attribute, as that will just copy the attribute as-is. Your existing `xsl:attribute` is just being ignored because you can't add an attribute onto this copied attribute.

Just remove the `xsl:copy` from the template, and just create a whole new attribute

```
<xsl:template match="@Id">
   <xsl:attribute name="Id">
     <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $uid-chars, $uid-mask)"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this would update by the `Id` of the `User` element as well as the `Session` element. If you did want to restrict it to just the `Session` attribute, you could use these two templates instead:

```
<xsl:template match="Session/@Id">
   <xsl:attribute name="Id">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $uid-chars, $uid-mask)"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@Id">
    <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
```